# Javafx My CategoryAxis of LineChart just show the last item when first run the LineChart

Tags: javafx, linechart

I am new for Javafx, and I try to make a LineChart for my data.I referenced the samples of Javafx and use a Button to paint the LineChart, but the CategoryAxis of LineChart just show the last item when first click the Button. And it works when I click it again.

[when I first click it, just show the last item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxSFo.png)

[when I click it again, it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wegAD.png)

I make the linechart by Scene Builder.

```
series = new XYChart.Series<String,Double>();
        series.setName("年份");
        String[] years = new String[related.length];
        int j = 0;
        for (Years y : year) {
            years[j++] = y.getYear();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < related.length; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Double>(years[i], related[i]));
        }
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
```

I wonder that it maybe caused by wrong initialize, but I can not find it.

Comment: `years[j] = y.getYear()+j; j++` try this in your first for loop

Comment: years.length can be the problem too. if related.length is 1 then you only see one year. so make sure related.length is correct when you init your charts